# How do I look in a string with text inside quotations, but ignoring anything inside brackets using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, double-quotes, square-bracket, quotation-marks

For example my string is:

```
var str = 'Hello "Counts1 [ignore1] Counts2 [ignore2] Counts3 [ignore3] Count these too"';
```

How would I get everything inside the string that is inside quotations ignoring the characters inside the brackets?

So for example a regex to collect: "Counts1", "Counts2", "Counts3", "Count these too"

So far I only got:

```
var regex = /".*?"/g;
```

It outputs:

```
"Counts1 [ignore1] Counts2 [ignore2] Counts3 [ignore3]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: `/(?<="|\] )[\w ]+(?="| \[)/g`

Positive lookbehind `(?<="|\] )` makes sure that `[\w ]+` has either `"` or `]`  to the left.
Positive lookahead `(?="| \[)` makes sure that `[\w ]+` has either `"` or  `[` to the right.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i968ON/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following non-regex approach that also supports nested square brackets:

```js
const extract = (str) => {
    let result = [], start = 0, i=0, level = 0, inquote=false;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        switch (str[i]) {
            case '"':
                if (inquote && !level) {
                    if (start < i) {
                        result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
                    }
                    start = i + 1;
                } else {
                    start = i+1;
                }
                inquote = !inquote;
                break;
            case '[':
                if (inquote) {
                  if (start < i && inquote && !level) {
                    result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
                  }
                  ++level;
                }
                break;
            case ']':
                if (inquote) {
                    if (level > 0) {  
                        --level;
                    }
                    if (level == 0) {
                        start = i + 1;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
 
    if (start < i)
        result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
   
    return result;
}
console.log(extract('Hello "Counts1 [ignore1] Counts2 [ignore2] Counts3 [ignore3] Count these too"'));
console.log(extract('Hello "Counts1 [[ignore1] this [2]] Counts2 [ignore2] Counts3 [ignore3] Count these too"'));
console.log(extract('"Counts1 [[ignore1] [2]] Counts2 [ignore2] Count these too" and [junk], and "maybe this, too [not this]"'));
```